# The 100-rep bonus is not added to my Stack Overflow account after opening accounts on Meta and Server Fault

Tags: support, association-bonus

I had opened an account on Server Fault some time ago, but there were no 100 additional points added to my SO account.

Today I have registered here on Meta and then I got the message "`Your Meta account has been associated with three other accounts`" and then another `"Your Stack Overflow and Server Fault account has 100 points associated"`.

But where are the points for my SO and the other accounts? Ok, I am not completely greedy but this what offered as a functionality and bonus.

Comment: Hm... I got rep on my SU account when I associated it with my SO, SF and meta accounts. I only got 100 rep, but none of them (SO, SF, and meta) had 200 rep to start with.

Comment: All my accounts are connected and didnt get rep on any of them!

Comment: @jer You need at least 200 reputation on at least one account to get the bonus reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a one-way bonus. You get 100 points on Meta, but not on your SO account.